# Position pagination Javafx css

Tags: javafx

How can i move the pagination to the bottom right while the content of the pagination stays centered

```
<Pagination fx:id="paging" maxPageIndicatorCount="5" pageCount="0" prefHeight="1010.0" prefWidth="1150.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work, i put pagination in stackpane along with content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Page controls and page info right aligned**

You can use this CSS to align the pagination controls to the right.

```
.pagination {
    -fx-page-information-alignment: right;
}
.pagination > .pagination-control > .control-box {
    -fx-alignment: bottom-right;
    -fx-padding: 0.416em 1.1em 0 0;
}
```

The right padding of `1.1em` on the control box is to allow room for the right aligned page information (the thing that says "x/N" where x is the current page and N is the max pages).

**Page controls right aligned with no page info**

If you don't want page information at all then you can make the right alignment `0em` instead of `1.1em` (or just define no padding as the default right padding is 0), and set `-fx-page-information-visible: false` instead of setting `-fx-page-information-alignment`.

```
.pagination {
    -fx-page-information-visible: false;
}
.pagination > .pagination-control > .control-box {
    -fx-alignment: bottom-right;
}
```

**Centering page content**

To have the content of each page centered, place each page in a StackPane as in the example.

**How to learn how to write this yourself**

Info on styling Pagination is available in:

- [CSS reference guide Pagination section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pagination).
- modena.css file found in your JavaFX installation, for example:

  - javafx-controls-17.0.0.1-mac.jar -> com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css.

**Example App**

[image: paginate]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PageAlign extends Application {
    private static final String CUSTOM_PAGINATION_CSS = """
            data:text/css,
            .pagination {
                -fx-background-color: lemonchiffon;
                -fx-page-information-alignment: right;
            }
            .pagination > .pagination-control > .control-box {
                -fx-alignment: bottom-right;
                -fx-padding: 0.416em 1.1em 0 0;
            }
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Pagination pagination = new Pagination();
        pagination.getStylesheets().add(CUSTOM_PAGINATION_CSS);
        pagination.setPageFactory(this::generatePage);
        pagination.setMaxPageIndicatorCount(6);
        pagination.setPageCount(6);
        pagination.setPrefSize(250, 140);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pagination));
        stage.show();
    }

    private StackPane generatePage(Integer idx) {
        StackPane page = new StackPane(
                new Label("Page Content " + (idx + 1))
        );
        page.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");

        return page;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```